# align image next to text

Tags: html, css

I am trying to display image and text like in this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/py8NX.jpg. But I am facing 2 issues on my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rwcbdk38/1/)

1. background image doesn't show up.
2. Contents stack up even when there is space is right. I believe its some extra padding/margin I have in code but not sure where.

### HTML

```
<section class="freedom_carousel">
  <ul class="two-col">
    <li class="pen"> 
      <span class="icon-text"> <em>THis is </em> text text text</span> 
    </li>
    <li class="phone"> 
      <span class="icon-text"> <em>THis is </em> text text text</span> 
    </li>
    <li class="arrow"> 
      <span class="icon-text"> <em>THis is </em> text text text</span> 
    </li>
    <li class="download"> 
      <span class="icon-text"> <em>THis is </em> text text text text</span>   
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: Assuming your URLs are correct, to fix the background issue, take the space out of the selector. `.two-col li .phone` should be `.two-col li.phone`

Comment: Perfect that worked. But the image is a little above the text. Its not aligned with the text. is there a way I can fix that?

Comment: If you can replicate the issue so I can see it on jsFiddle I can probably help. Without seeing the actual images and layout I can't do much.

Comment: I am sorry about that. Here is the fiddle link. http://jsfiddle.net/rwcbdk38/5/

Comment: You can use the `background-position` property to handle that. See the first list item at  http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/rwcbdk38/6/

Comment: TRY - http://jsfiddle.net/rwcbdk38/7/

Comment: I know I am being a stickler. I apologize for that. when there are 2 or more lines of text, the image aligns in the center of the paragraph. I’d like it to align with the first line of text.

Comment: @user3861559 TRY - http://jsfiddle.net/rwcbdk38/8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your styles required some serious reworking, take a look here: [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/rwcbdk38/9/)

### HTML

```
<section class="freedom_carousel"> <!--Freedom section -->
  <ul class="two-col left-col">
    <li class="pen"> <span class="icon-text"><em>THis is </em> text text text text text text text </span></li>
    <li class="phone"> <span class="icon-text"><em>THis is </em> text text text text text text text </span></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="two-col right-col">
    <li class="arrow"> <span class="icon-text"><em>THis is </em> text text text text text text text </span></li>
    <li class="download"> <span class="icon-text"><em>THis is </em> text text text text text text text </span></li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

### CSS

```
.left-col, .right-col {
  list-style: none;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.two-col li {
  padding-left: 30px;
}

.two-col li.pen{
  background: url("https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/inverticons-stroke-vol-3/32/pen_write_edit_sketch_draw_compose-20.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

***EDIT:***
Here is a sample media query for your mobile needs. It is currently set to apple when the screen size is less than 450px wide (you can customize this to your needs): [**DEMO2**](http://jsfiddle.net/rwcbdk38/11/)

```
@media (max-width:450px) {
    .freedom_carousel ul.two-col li span.icon-text {
         text-align: center; 
    }
    .left-col, .right-col {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .two-col li {
        padding-left: 0px;
        text-align: center;
        padding-top: 50px;
    }
    .two-col li.pen, .two-col li.phone, .two-col li.arrow, .two-col li.download  {
        background-position: 50%;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can add `background-position: 0px 5px;` to the `.two-col li.pen` (and similar) classes to help position the icons if needed. (0px is for the X value and 5px is currently set for the y value but they can be adjusted as needed).

Comment: Hi JRulle, That worked perfectly fine.

I am not trying ti mobile version of it. I want image and text to stack one over the other like in this pic (http://i.imgur.com/vEOlQmn.jpg). the image has different image than what I need but overall structure of stacking that I am looking for is the same.I tried various methods but I am not able to get it to stack.

Comment: @user3861559, you will need to use a media query to make the page behave differently under a certain screen size... [**DEMO2**](http://jsfiddle.net/rwcbdk38/11/)

Comment: Yeah, I was using media queries but I wasn't able to get it to stack. I believe I wasn't using background properties correctly. Now they do stack, but the image and the text over lap with each other (as in the fiddle link)

Comment: they aren't overlapping when i look at it in chrome. you could try changing the padding of `.two-col li` to meet your needs... or separating the '<li>`'s with some margins